# How order doctrine query for many-to-many relationship?

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, many-to-many, schema

i use doctrine 1.2 and here is my schema:

```
ProviderProduct:
 columns:
   provider_id: 
     type: integer
     primary: true
   product_id:
     type: integer
     primary: true
   num:
     type: integer
     default: 0
     unsigned: true
Provider: 
 columns:
   name: {type: string(255), notnull: true, notblank: true, unique: true}
 relations:
   Products:
     class: Product
     local: provider_id
     foreign: product_id
     refClass: ProviderProduct
Product:
 columns:
    #a lot of columns
 relations:
   Providers:
     class: Provider
     local: product_id
     foreign: provider_id
     refClass: ProviderProduct
```

What i want is get product with max num (this is ammount) for specific provider.
I tried this query:

```
$query = Doctrine_Query::create()->select('p.*')
                                     ->from('Product p')
                                     ->innerJoin('p.Providers pr')
                                     ->where('pr.name = ?', 'WhiteStore')
                                     ->orderBy('ProviderProduct.num');
$query->fetchOne();
```

The result sql query:

```
SELECT p.* FROM product p 
INNER JOIN provider_product p3 ON (p.id = p3.product_id) 
INNER JOIN provider p2 ON p2.id = p3.provider_id, provider_product p4 
WHERE (p2.name = ?) ORDER BY p4.num
```

As you can see it doesnt order by num field. So, what is the right dql for my task ?

Answer (score 0):

[How order doctrine query for many-to-many relationship?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16014808/how-order-doctrine-query-for-many-to-many-relationship/40155950#40155950)

You can use following construction:

```
$query = Doctrine_Query::create()->select('p.*')
->from('Product p')
->innerJoin('p.Providers pr')
->where('pr.name = ?', 'WhiteStore')
->orderBy('p.Providers.ProviderProduct.num');
```

The not native behavior of Doctrine 1 is creating an invisible alias for many-to-many relation. You can use this alias for building right order.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to relate refClass too:

```
ProviderProduct:
  columns:
    provider_id: 
    type: integer
    primary: true
  product_id:
    type: integer
    primary: true
  num:
    type: integer
    default: 0
    unsigned: true
relations:
  Provider: { foreignAlias: ProviderProduct }
  Product:  { foreignAlias: ProviderProduct }
```

And then relate through reffClass to get the number:

```
$query = Doctrine_Query::create()->select('p.*')
  ->from('Product p')
  ->innerJoin('p.ProviderProduct pp')
  ->innerJoin('pp.Provider pr')
  ->where('pr.name = ?', 'WhiteStore')
  ->orderBy('pp.num DESC') // to get de max first
  ->groupBy('p.id') // if any duplicates
  ->limit(1);

$product = $query->fetchOne();
```